# Запуск Unit тестов в IDEA

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, юнит-тесты

Когда я использую аннотацию @Test, IDEA отображает зелененький треугольничек, позволяющий удобно запустить его.

Если я создаю Unit тест в андроид проекте, то запускается эмулятор андроида. Но для тестирования бизнес логики, которая не связана с андроидом это явно избыточно. Есть какая-то возможность, разделить, что эти тесты будут с андриодом, а эти с консолью? (желательно чтобы можно было и запускать через треугольничек, удобно же)

П.с. И ещё один момент, я так понимаю поддержки лямбд в андроиде до сих пор нет? Но в тоже время IDEA сворачивает анонимный класс и отображает его как лямбду. Может я могу и писать эти самые лямбды, а IDEA будет их уже превращать в анонимные классы?

Comment: по идее так быть не должно. проверьте настройки вашей IDEA. не связанные вопросы стоит задавать по отдельности.

Answer (score 2):

Скорей всего вы пишите UI тесты, в то время как вам нужны обычные Unit тесты. UI тесты находятся в папке `/src/androidTest`, Unit тесты в папке `/src/test`. Вам нужен второй вариант.

IDEA сворачиваем анонимный класс в лямбду только в редакторе. Если потом нажать на этот код, он будет выглядеть как обычно. Т.е. это своеобразная "подсветка синтаксиса". Однако вы можете подключить [retrolambd'y](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) и тогда вы сможете использовать лямбды и некоторые другие особености Java 8, в том виде, в котором они есть там. Однако "под капотом" это будут все те же анонимные классы.

Так же в новой [Android Stuio Preview 6](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/java-8-language-features-support-update.html) есть поддержка Java 8

Comment: О, спасибо за лямбды ) А Unit тесты кстати нет, я пишу в папке test. Скорее всего она у меня как то криво распозналась, но я не понимаю что и как там пометить.

Comment: Надо было просто переключится на них в Build Variants ) Это кстати и было написано на примере теста, но я его сразу удалил, и не заметил комментария.